# Why code don't work DateTemplate with VisualStates

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

Why this code work fine with `triggers` but not work with `VisualStates` `PointerOver` and `Pressed`?

```
<Grid>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <UserControl>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="xxx">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="text1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" From="Azure" To="Red"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="text2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="text1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" From="Azure" To="Red"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="text1" Text="{Binding Path=surname}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="text2" Text="{Binding Path=salary}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </UserControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```